# Problem Adding Firebase Firestore To My Project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Firstly, I would like to let you know that I have user Firebase Firestore several times before and have not faced such an error... I have followed the process correctly step by step and, because it was not working, I also tried to add firebase to an existing project and it has still given me errors. Below is there error which I get :

`2020-05-21 09:32:15.775788+0530 Job App[61230:1180572] [GoogleDataTransport][I-GDTCOR001006] (/Users/tejas/Desktop/Files/Coding/Main Projects/Job App/Pods/GoogleDataTransport/GoogleDataTransport/GDTCORLibrary/GDTCOREvent.m:59) : There was an error saving the new counter value to disk.`

Keep in mind that this error only pops up the first time I run the app on the simulator, then when I rerun it this error is gone. My app also doesn't even crash and the build always succeeds despite this error. Here is my app information:

[image]

Here is the code in my app delegate

```
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool
    {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        return true
    }
```

My GoogleService-Info.plist file has the correct bundle ID :

[image]

Here is the file inspector of my GoogleService-Info.plist:

[image]

Here is the code inside my podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '13.0'

target 'Job App' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Job App
pod 'lottie-ios'
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
end
```

Here is the message I get from the Firebase App Setup Wizard :

[image]

These are the pods under the pods folder :

[image]

It keeps on loading for a very long time and I'm sure that something is going wrong...
I really really appreciate your help! Feel free to ask me anything if you need some more information to solve this problem. Thank you so much again!

Comment: Update : I also tried it on a different project now... This error still shows up and firebase wizard is still loading for a very long time

Comment: Posting the same question more than once is frowned upon. Post only once.  99% of the time you will get an answer.

Comment: @TheSwiftTeen Have you attempted skipping the installation, running the dashboard & waiting. In my experience, i've never waited for it to confirm as it takes 20-30 minutes. You can contact firebase directly, which might be best as they can see more then we can. https://firebase.google.com/support

Answer (score 0):

Remember to uninstall the APP from the simulator if it was already installed before adding firebase.

Also in the pod file you must enter:

```
pod 'FirebaseFirestore'
```